# How to trigger different functions based on a radio button option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, radio-button

I'm having troubles trying to trigger two different functions based on a radio button option.

I have an autocomplete field, but the source must be setted by a radiobutton option. 
what can I do?

I have done this, so far:

```js
var autocompleteOne = [
  "Item 01",
  "Item 02",
  "Item 03",
  "Item 04",
  "Item 05"  
];

var autocompleteTwo = [
  "Item 01.2",
  "Item 02.2",
  "Item 03.2",
  "Item 04.2",
  "Item 05.2"  
];


$('#options').blur(function(){
  if(document.getElementById("optionA").attr(checked, true{
    $("#autocompleteCaseOne").autocomplete({              source: autocompleteOne
    });
  }
  if(document.getElementById("optionB").attr(checked, true{
    $("#autocompleteCaseTwo").autocomplete({              source: autocompleteTwo
    });
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Choosing option</label>
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="yes" id="optionA" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="no" id="optionB" />no
</div>
<div>
  <label>autocomplete function result</label>
  <input type="text" id="options" name="autocompleteOptions">
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your browser console. Your JavaScript has syntax errors.

Comment: Also there's really no point in mixing jQuery and native object lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost correct, but autocomplete function is not correct. The following is the correct full code.

```js
  $("input[name='options']").change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "yes") 
      $("#options").autocomplete({
          source: autocompleteOne
      });
    else if ($(this).val() == "no") 
      $("#options").autocomplete({
          source: autocompleteTwo
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to target the change radio button event, you should be using `.change()` or `.click()` to trigger a change in your autocomplete source.

Something like

```
$("input[name='options']").change(function(event) {
  if ($(this).val() == "yes") 
    $("#options").autocomplete('option', 'source', autocompleteOne);
  else if ($(this).val() == "no") 
    $("#options").autocomplete('option', 'source', autocompleteTwo);
});
```